# Cancel button on QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am running into an issue, when I choose not to Save my file and click "Cancel" on the system window the program will crash. Here is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "BasicEmail.py", line 166, in save_content
with open(file_name[0], 'w') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

This is the code I am using:

```
def save_content(self):
    file_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'Save File',os.getenv('HOME'))
    if file_name:
        with open(file_name[0], 'w') as f:
            my_text = self.content.toPlainText()
            f.write(my_text)
```

Thank you in advance. I know I must be missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `if file_name:` statement will always be `True` since the `getSaveFileName()` function always returns a tuple, which has the following structure: `(filename, filters)`, it is best to get the name and verify that the string is not empty.

```
def save_content(self):
    file_name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', os.getenv('HOME'))
    if file_name != "":
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            my_text = self.content.toPlainText()
            f.write(my_text)
```

*Plus:* You can use `QtCore.QDir.homePath()` instead of `os.getenv('HOME')`

Comment: The string is empty. From what I've read it returns a string None or null when the operation is canceled. Which is likely why it is a problem.

Comment: I have tried it. The only thing that won't work is with open(file_name, 'w') it has to be written open(file_name[0], 'w'). When I print file_name before the If statement, it prints ('', ''). And then the traceback.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BasicEmail.py", line 167, in save_content
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple`

Comment: I am sorry. I am not familiar with the website. I use to be told to wait. I just have just marked your answer correct.